# Is the following substitution legal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to prove that from

$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$ and $a+b+c \neq0$

it follows that

$4b^2-4ac=0$.

Am I allowed to substitute $ac=b^2$ in $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$ and if i prove the resulting equality is true then it will follow that $ac=b^2$ because otherwise the resulting equality wouldn't be true??

Answer (score 3):

Since your actual question concerns the legality of a substitution, my answer is a simple **no**. The reason is because this is a good example of a backwards proof. You are actually assuming what you are trying to prove. You want to show a statement of the form $p\to q$, but what you are doing is trying to obtain something of the form $(q\land p)\to r$, where $r$ is some true equality. This does not really constitute a valid proof. You need to work *toward* the statement you are trying to prove true, not *from* it.

Answer (score 2):

The straight answer to your question is "no". However working backwards can sometimes give a clue as to how to work forwards.

There are some hints in other answers. I would note that the condition $a+b+c\neq 0$ together with the fact that the given expression is cubic and the final conclusion clearly belongs to a quadratic very strongly combine to suggest that you will be dividing by $a+b+c$ at some stage in your proof.

The strategy of isolating $b$ can be used to get you off the ground as follows:

$$a^3+c^3=3abc-b^3$$

Factorise both sides $$(a+c)(a^2-ac+c^2)=b(3ac-b^2)$$

Now you want $a+b+c$ on the left-hand side so add $b(a^2-ac+c^2)$ to both sides

$$(a+b+c)(a^2-ac+c^2)=b(a^2+c^2+2ac-b^2)=b((a+c)^2-b^2)=b(a+b+c)(a-b+c)$$

Now you can cancel $a+b+c$ from both sides and continue.

This is not the best or most elegant way, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have proved in that case the converse; that is $4b^2 - 4ac = 0 \implies a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 3abc$

Not all relations including an equal sign are if and only if; for example 
$x = -1 \implies x^2 = 1$ but the converse is false.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that
$$
0=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc= (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca).
$$
Since $a+b+c\neq 0$, the second factor is equal to zero, i.e., we have
$ (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 =0$. Over the real numbers this means that $a=b=c$. In particular, $b^2=ac$.

Comment: Can you please help me with [this question](math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159519/evaluating-coefficients-of-a-symmetric-polynomial) ?